# Setting constraint influence in Python behaves differently inside vs outside 'If' statement?

Tags: python, scripting, constraints

The code snippet [below](http://pasteall.org/1444998/python) contains a block code; running once in the global scope, and once inside the else branch of a condition:

```
>>> bpy.context.selected_pose_bones[0].constraints[0].influence = 0.0
>>> mat1 = bpy.context.selected_pose_bones[0].matrix.copy()
>>> bpy.context.selected_pose_bones[0].constraints[0].influence = 1.0
>>> mat2 = bpy.context.selected_pose_bones[0].matrix.copy()
>>> result = "Good" if (mat1 != mat2) else "Bad"
>>> print("Result: %s" % (result))
```

Result: Good

```
>>> 
>>> if (armature == None or armature.type != 'ARMATURE'):
...     print("Selected object must be an armature")
... elif (bpy.context.selected_pose_bones == None or len(bpy.context.selected_pose_bones) != 1):
...     print("Select at least 1 pose bone")
... else:
...     bpy.context.selected_pose_bones[0].constraints[0].influence = 0.0
...     mat1 = bpy.context.selected_pose_bones[0].matrix.copy()
...     bpy.context.selected_pose_bones[0].constraints[0].influence = 1.0
...     mat2 = bpy.context.selected_pose_bones[0].matrix.copy()
...     result = "Good" if (mat1 != mat2) else "Bad"
...     print("Result: %s" % (result))
...
```

Result: Bad

From some reason though, it doesn’t evaluate correctly when inside a condition.
What is going on? what am I missing?

Comment: Hi. Please include any relevant code in the question body itself.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13899286/190597) warns that for performance reasons,
Blender does not update certain attributes (like `obj.matrix_world`) until necessary.
I think your experiment suggests that `bpy.context.selected_pose_bones[0]` falls into this category.

The same linked answer shows that you can force an update using

```
bpy.context.scene.update()
```

Let's try it here:

```
armature = bpy.data.objects['Armature']
if (armature == None or armature.type != 'ARMATURE'):
    print("Selected object must be an armature")
elif (bpy.context.selected_pose_bones == None or len(bpy.context.selected_pose_bones) != 1):
    print("Select at least 1 pose bone")
else:
    bpy.context.selected_pose_bones[0].constraints[0].influence = 0.0
    bpy.context.scene.update()
    mat1 = bpy.context.selected_pose_bones[0].matrix.copy()
    bpy.context.selected_pose_bones[0].constraints[0].influence = 1.0
    bpy.context.scene.update()
    mat2 = bpy.context.selected_pose_bones[0].matrix.copy()
    print(mat1)
    print(mat2)        
    result = "Good" if (mat1 != mat2) else "Bad"
    print("Result: %s" % (result))
```

yields

```
<Matrix 4x4 (1.0000, 0.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 0.0000, -1.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 1.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 0.0000,  0.0000, 1.0000)>
<Matrix 4x4 (1.0000, 0.0000,  0.0000, -0.0494)
            (0.0000, 0.0000, -1.0000, -0.0543)
            (0.0000, 1.0000,  0.0000,  0.1240)
            (0.0000, 0.0000,  0.0000,  1.0000)>
Result: Good
```

---

When you enter the commands individually on the command line,
Blender seems to call `bpy.context.scene.update()` in the background for you.
When all the commands are placed in the body of an `if-statement`, then the commands are not executed until the entire if-statement is written and sent to the Python interpreter.
The interpreter then executes all of the statements in the body of the `if-statement` very quickly, one after another. Now, Blender does not have time to call `bpy.context.scene.update()` in the background between each statement.

This explains why you saw a difference in behavior.